# Is there a simple way to combine Factories in Java?

Tags: java, factory

Suppose I have interfaces of factory classes `FactoryA` and `FactoryB` with methods for producing objects of type `A` and `B` respectively, and suppose I have implementations of these interfaces. Now suppose I need a factory class `FactoryAB` that implements both interfaces, i.e., produces both `A` and `B`. Is there a simple way to combine the implementations of interfaces `FactoryA` and `FactoryB` to get a `FactoryAB`?

**Edit:**
This is motivated by a situation where a class needs a large number of factories to produces a large number of different objects. In this case it seems to me more convenient to just have a single *large* factory that produces all the needed components instead of having to keep track of many *small* factories.

The main goal is to not have to write too much code to achieve this. Perhaps, some other pattern is more appropriate for this scenario?

**Edit2:**
Essentially I would like to go from having bloated code like:

```
public class Consumer {
 FactoryA factoryAImpl;
 FactoryB factoryBImpl;
 // ...
 FactoryY factoryYImpl;
 FactoryZ factoryZImpl;

 public Consumer(FactoryA factoryA, FactoryB factoryB, ..., FactoryZ factoryZ) {
   // ...
 }
 //...
}
```

To having compact/simple code like:

```
public class Consumer {
 FactoryAtoZ factoryAtoZImpl;

 public Consumer(FactoryAtoZ factoryAtoZ) {
   // ...
 }
 //...
}
```

Comment: Are `A` and `B` interfaces?

Comment: @immibis How could they be if they can be "created" aka "instantiated".

Comment: Are `FactoryA`, `FactoryB`, and `FactoryAB` interfaces, abstract classes, or concrete classes? Why is it difficult to manually write `FactoryAB`?

Comment: @mbomb007 well, if they're *not* interfaces, and one isn't a superclasss of the other, then it's *impossible* to have an object which is both.

Comment: @mbomb007 the factory would create instanes of concrete classes implementing the interface.

Comment: They are interfaces. FactoryAB implements both of the other interfaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difficulty is. Create a FactoryAB class containing an instance of FactoryA, an instance of FactoryB, and delegating to these two factories).

Comment: A and B each have different interfaces. One is not a sub-interface of the other.

Comment: @JBNizet as in implement the methods of FactoryAB by calling the appropriate instance of one of the two factories? Yes I thought of that, but this seems like a lot of code for something conceptually simple.

Comment: A lot of code? That's 5 lines of code. See Julia Leder's answer.

Comment: @JBNizet not if the factories have large interfaces. Also I was thinking of the general problem when, potentially, many factories should be combined to produce many different types of objects. I am sorry I was not clear about this.

Comment: What do you gain by combining two factories in a single class in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet: I am trying to keep the number of factories I need low. See the added explanation to the question. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this by dynamically generating a Proxy and delegating the method calls to the concrete objects *if and only if* you have a reliable way of determining which delegate to hand this off to.

First of all you're going to need an interface that combines your existing factories

```
public interface FactoryAB extends FactoryA, FactoryB {
}
```

(note that lack of methods)

Then you need to create the Proxy

```
    DelegatingHandler handler = new DelegatingHandler(new ConcreteFactoryA(), new ConcreteFactoryB());
    FactoryAB factoryAb = (FactoryAB)Proxy.newProxyInstance(handler.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{FactoryAB.class}, handler);
```

And finally the `InvocationHandler` to do the actual method interception for you

```
public class DelegatingHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final List<Object> factoryDelegates;

    public DelegatingHandler(Object ... factories) {
        factoryDelegates = Arrays.asList(factories);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        for (Object factory : factoryDelegates) {
            Method[] declaredMethods = factory.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method declaredMethod : declaredMethods) {
                if (declaredMethod.getReturnType().equals(method.getReturnType())) {
                    return method.invoke(factory, args);
                }
            }
        };
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works by providing a list of concrete factories to delegate to, and on every method call looks at these factories to find one that has a method that matches the return type.  When it finds one it will invoke the method you called on the delegate factory and return whatever it returns.

I suspect you might need more involved checking to find the right delegate, but only you know that.

Using this you can add new factories to your delegate by merely adding to the `FactoryAB` interface and injecting the required delegate into the `DelegatingHandler`, no further work required.

You should note that using this method, all of your calls are now being routed by reflection instead of direct method calls

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with Composition:

```
public class FactoryAB implements FactoryA, FactoryB
{
   FactoryA factoryAImpl = new FactoryAImplementor();
   FactoryB factoryBImpl = new FactoryBImplementor();

   public ObjectA getObjectA()  {
        return factoryAImpl.getObjectA();
   }

   public ObjectB getObjectB()  {
        return factoryBImpl.getObjectB();
   }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but say the factories for A and B have very large interfaces? Or if many factories needed to be combined. Then this would result in a lot of code. I was hoping for a more scalable solution (code wise).

Comment: If you have FactoryAB which HAS to implement FactoryA and FactoryB interfaces, there is no way around actually having the code for both  interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **composite** concept and **factory method** pattern to combine both `FactoryA` and `FactoryB` interfaces. Assuming you have a common interface `AB` and `public A getA()` the factory method for `FactoryA` and `public B getB()` the factory method for `FactoryB`:

```
public class ABFactory implements FactoryA, FactoryB {
    public AB GetAB(InterfaceType type) {
        AB implementation = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case InterfaceType.AType:
                implementation = getA();
                break;
            case InterfaceType.BType:
                implementation = getB();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return implementation;
    }
   public A getA() {
      return new FactoryAImpl().getA();
   }

   public B getB() {
      return new FactoryBImpl().getB();
   }

}
```

assuming

```
public enum InterfaceType {
    AType,
    BType
}
```